# Powershell Script for looping through multiple O365 tenants

Tags: powershell, office365, powershell-remoting

Community,

I have a script I pieced together online, that allows me to add a domain/sender to the block list via the Spam filter in Exchange Online. Currently, the script is written for one tenant. I would like it to loop through about 5 tenants, each with different credentials.

I was told I need to create PSCredential Objects, but I'm unsure of how to go about this. Or where to place the code.

Script:

```
# First we need credentials to use to connect to O365
Write-Host "Enter your O365 Global Administrator credentials"
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
```

## Then we need to define the PS session to connect to O365

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

## Now we Open the Session

```
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber
```

## Prompt for vars

```
$domainlist = Read-Host -Prompt 'Domain(s) to add to Block list (press ENTER if none, use single space between entries): '
$addresslist = Read-Host -Prompt 'Email address to add to Block list (press ENTER if none, use single space between entries): '
$domains = $domainlist -split " "
$addresses = $addresslist -split " "
```

## Add Domains to list, if any

```
if (!$domainlist) {
    Write-Host "No domains to add...skipping"
} else {
    Write-Host "Adding domain name(s) to Default spam Block list...."
    Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity Default -BlockedSenderDomains @{Add=$domains}
}
```

## Add email addresses to list, if any

```
if (!$addresslist) {
    Write-Host "No addresses to add...skipping"
} else {
    Write-Host "Adding email address(es) to Default spam Block list...."
    Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy -Identity Default -BlockedSenders @{Add=$addresses}
}
```

## Close the Session or bad things happen!!!

```
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to provide credentials in non-interactive mode, you can create a PSCredential object in the following way.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText –Force

$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

Use it as part of a loop, and you should be able to create PSSesions automatically.

But the rest of your script is still interactive, and it still needs your input.

You could refer to the following link:

[PowerShell – How to create a PSCredential object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/)